# How to restrict a template class to except only enum data type

Tags: c++, enums

I have written a class where i am using an enum data types. Now i want to generalize it to work with any type of enum data list. Is there any way to write a template class which will accept only enum data types;

My question is how to restrict a template class to accept only enum data types.

Comment: to be clear - only values of a specific enum, or any type that is an enum?

Comment: I mean different types of enum, not the different value of an enum type.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple in c++11 you can do [`std::is_enum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum). here is the example from the site.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {};

enum E {};

enum class Ec : int {};

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_enum<A>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_enum<E>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_enum<Ec>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_enum<int>::value << '\n';
}
```

Here is a class that uses the feature.

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    static_assert(std::is_enum<T>::value,"not an enum");
};
```

You could also use boost's [`is_enum`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_enum.html) in an identical fashion if you don't have c++11, remember boost is open source so you can check out the code if you don't want the whole thing.

Comment: Thank you @aaronman for your suggestion, but i am not using C++11 compiler. I am getting error "type_traits: No such file or directory".

Comment: @rajenpandit well you should update but I'll try to figure something out

Comment: thanks @aaronman, i will update my compiler or i will use boost library. thanks for support.

Answer (score 2):

Using `<type_traits>`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    static_assert(std::is_enum<T>::value, "Must be an enum type");
    ....
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The following uses SFINAE instead of `static_assert`:

```
template<typename EventType, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<EventType>::value>::type* = nullptr>
class EventSystem {
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P47xnKE75)

Comment: static_assert is available since C++11.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I forgot that static_assert has two forms. And one of them is available from C++11 and the other from C++17. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Without using C++11, you can do it by specifying the `enum` type as the template parameter type, if you want to limit it to a *specific* enumerated type:

```
#include <iostream>

enum fred { A, B };

template <fred F>
void f(void) { std::cout << F << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    f<B>();  // works
    f<1>(); // generates an error
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe for you suggestion, actually i want to pass different types of enum data during class creation. for example `enum A{a,a1,a2}` `enum B{b,b1,b2}` two enum types are there and i want to use any one of them at once.Is there any way to do that without using c++11 library.

Comment: @rajenpandit : Unfortunately, I can't think of a way offhand, other than maybe looking to Boost's `is_enum`.  If I do think of a way, I will update my answer.  Until then, good luck.

Comment: thanks @Joe, i will update my compiler or i will use boost library. thanks for support.